# Licensing header for protecting the idea

Tags: licensing

A student asked me which license suited best for her project, but I couldn't reply.

Here's what she told me:

- The student project was in collaboration with a brand;
- The goal of the project was to help to brand to make new tools and to grow;
- She didn't sign anything, no legal document, at first. But when the project was finished, her professor told the students their had to sign a document he forgot to give. This document stated the "[student] yields graciously to [the brand] every work...". She didn't sign it as is, but added that she wanted the following point;
- All she wants is if [the brand] uses the whole project or part of it, internally or publically, they mention her name noticeably everywhere her work can be visible.

Is there a license or something she can write on a `LICENSE` file, or at the top of the header of the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the student is not performing [work for hire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_for_hire) (and she probably isn't) then she owns the copyright in the work. Irrespective she has a [moral right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_rights) in the work - outside of the US this includes a right of attribution.

She can licence it however she wants. She can choose not to licence it as well.

Currently she holds all the cards and if the brand owner wants to use the project they will have to agree to her terms.

Comment: Thank you, Dale. So a [CC Attribution-NoDerivatives 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/) can be used, right? That's the one she wants.